# Show default Gmap winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, google-maps

I was using Gmap in winform,
while gmap loading will be show default like this :

[image]

I wanna Gmap show default map in my local(latitude - longitude) which I give before Gmap load
and with zooming like I want like this

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```
GMap.NET.WindowsForms.GMapControl map;
map.Position = new PointLatLng(Latitude, Longitude);
```

Comment: Hi, thank for anwer me, I think there is a way in code with gmap control, but I dont know how to set it, I am using code like this   https://i.stack.imgur.com/oATbW.png

Comment: Please [edit] your question explaining you are using a C# GMap SDK and include that image.

Comment: thank bro, I found it, likt this : GMap.NET.WindowsForms.GMapControl map 
 map.Position = new PointLatLng(Latitude, Longitude);